# Why there is an extra line of 8 bytes between two mallocs?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I met a question when I try to understand the memory allocating in C/C++, I know the function `malloc()` will allocate an area in the type of **heap**, so does `new` in C++, so I wrote the following code:

```
char *a;
a = (char *)malloc(8);
a [0] = 'a';
char *b;
b = new char[8];
char *c;
c = (char *)malloc(8);
c [0] = 'b';
```

I use `g++ -g` to compile and use `gdb` to see the status when running, and get the following result:

```
(gdb) i locals
a = 0x804b008 "a"
b = 0x804b018 ""
c = 0x804b028 "b"
```

and

```
(gdb) x/48b a
0x804b008:  97  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x804b010:  0   0   0   0   17  0   0   0
0x804b018:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x804b020:  0   0   0   0   17  0   0   0
0x804b028:  98  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0x804b030:  0   0   0   0   -47 15  2   0
```

As we can see, there is an extra line of **8 bytes** between the two `malloc`s, I don't know why this line exists, please tell me what is it.

Comment: Could it be the size of allocated memory block? When you allocate memory on the heap the size of the block is usually stored with it so that `free()` can later deallocate it.

Comment: @rozina I guess not, the value here might be nonsense, as I modified the size of blocks, the value changed to an unrelated number. Also, I re-edited the question.

Comment: @rozina I don't know why folks vote down this question, so if you think it make sense, please vote up, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your memory dump, you "own" 24 bytes (3 x 8 bytes), but you are shows 48 bytes (6 x 8 bytes). I've labelled up what is "yours" and what is not here:

```
0x804b008:  97  0   0   0   0   0   0   0    <- Yours
0x804b010:  0   0   0   0   17  0   0   0    <- Not yours 
0x804b018:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    <- Yours
0x804b020:  0   0   0   0   17  0   0   0    <- Not yours 
0x804b028:  98  0   0   0   0   0   0   0    <- Yours
0x804b030:  0   0   0   0   -47 15  2   0    <- Not yours
```

You are looking at data that is "between allocations". There is no definition of what it will contain - it is undefined by any C or C++ standards (the particular C or C++ library MAY define this in some way, for example, but it's not necessary for the C++ library to document this in any way).

In many C or C++ libraries, this area is used to store information about where the next lump of (free?) data is located, but to me this doesn't look to be the case here.

Comment: I thought the memory allocation of `malloc` is like `variable` in stack, which is usually contiguous, so when I saw an extra line between each two areas, I got puzzled, even though I have known the allocation in **heap** is discrete. Now that C or C++ standard doesn't standard it, why both of them spare **8 bytes** here?

Comment: You are wrong about variables on the stack - if you have a mix of, say, `char x; int y; long z;`, there may well be "empty space" between the variables to align them to their natural size. But more importantly, `malloc` and `new` are definitely within their rights to add extra space for "administration purposes" in the space before/after your allocation. Further, by adjusting the size, the runtime library avoids some cases of heap fragmentation. However, how much, and where (if any) this padding/admin data is and ends up is not defined by the C and C++ standards - it's up to each vendor...

Comment: I meant that if we define variables of the same type like `int a, b, c`, usually, the addresses of a, b and c are contiguous, but it depends on the compiler, right?

Comment: If all variables are the same, then they will occupy contiguous space, yes. But that doesn't apply to `malloc`/`new` either way - there will be SOME extra space between allocations, sometimes simply to round it, and sometimes because the runtime needs the space for admin purposes. This is why I object to `new int` and similar constructs - it really wastes memory... [Sometimes it's unavoidable, of course]

Answer (score 3):

There's likely no particular significance to the 17 value, and it's certainly not part of your memory area or something that you should be reading or writing from your program.  When you use `malloc`, the memory returned may have been freed after use by some previous `malloc`, and consequently have old data hanging around in it.  The amount of memory requested may be rounded up to some size the `malloc` system prefers to deal with - such as 16, so you may or may not "own" those extra 8 bytes in the sense that a `realloc` would always give you them rather than shift you to some other memory area (but regardless, it's Undefined Behaviour if you try to read/modify them before such a `realloc`).  It's also legal for the `malloc` library to use surrounding memory for its own bookkeeping, and possible that the memory between your 8 byte allocations is still in use by some other library/bootstrap code.  Only the bytes/character's in the 8 byte area you definitely own, that you've explicitly overwritten with your own content, have predictable content.

Note that for `new`, there's a distinct syntax for requesting the array element be initialised to '\0':

```
b = new char[8]();
```

Answer (score 2):

Malloc (and new) just allocate contiguous blocks of addresses for your use.  They make no guarantees about what occurs in addresses that are not allocated.  This memory could be used for data structures to track what you have allocated.  It could be just unused memory that might get used on a later malloc or realloc call.  It may never get used or it may already be in use by some library you called either explicitly or implicitly.